# Twit API reply does not really reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

I'm currently writing a small Twitter Bot using nodejs and the [Twit API Client](https://github.com/ttezel/twit).

When I'm replying to a tweet, I use the following code:

```
T.post('statuses/update', { status: '@' + username + " " + id,  in_reply_to_status_id: id}, function(err, data, response) {
            if(err){
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(response);
        })
```

Where T is the correctly authenticated client, username is the username of the user with the tweet which I want to reply to and id is the id_str of the tweet I want to reply to.

But something wierd happens.

If i check my notifications, It looks like I replied to the tweet, showing them tied together.

But if I click on the tweet on my timeline, the response is not shown.

Unfortunaly, I can't post pictures, due to missing reputation, I hope you understand my problem. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue recently and the solution is simple yet stupid. If you reply to a tweet or just mention someone in your tweet with @username as the first thing in your tweet, it will act as a PM of sorts. If you just **move @username to the middle of the message or something, it will show up**, given that you also send the in_reply_to_status_id.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what khuderm proposed but I think the problem you have is the one referred to in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ttezel/twit/issues/6). Although a bit illogical, you should actually use `in_reply_to_status_id: id_str` instead of `in_reply_to_status_id: id`.

The former is simply the same id in a string form (surrounded by double quotes) and passing it without the quotes is causing the problem that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Try user.screen_name instead of username.

Comment: This should be a comment.